# HTTPS All the Docker Container in one domain? - Let's Encrypt

Tags: docker, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have domain called example.com which routed to 123.12.123.12 server.
And this is docker server so docker containers are like

- 123.12.123.12:1201
- 123.12.123.12:1202
- 123.12.123.12:1203

I am accessing this containers like

- http://example.com:1201
- http://example.com:1202
- http://example.com:1203

But my project is webapp using microphone so i need all my docker container secured with SSL. Projects developed with Node.js

Is there any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: I would encourage you to look at the https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/ controller. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/. It can solve your problem.